# Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 10 C++ typedef enum information disappeared

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, enums, windows-10, typedef

I have an app is working on Window 7 successfully and need to migrate it to Windows 10. So I have been trying to build it with Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 10.

There are some C# and C++ projects in the solution. The problem is that there is a huge data have numbers of structure and it has some enums passing from a C++ project to another C++ project's function as a parameter. But it is failed during runtime.

When I debug it, I realized that fields of enums are marked as "cannot obtain value". I refreshed it in watch window it changed to "undefined value".

The function in the second C++ project the whole data is unrecognized and I got the error below:

"Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that another memory is corrupt."

The same code works on Windows 7 Visual Studio 2012 correctly but not on Windows 10 Visual Studio 2012.

**enums are defined as below:**

```
typedef enum {
    item1,
    item2,
    item3,
    item4,
} enum_name;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. "typedef enum { item1, item2, item3, item4, } enum_name;" obviously has a typo, so we need to see real code that reproduces the problem to be able to help you

Comment: The fact that you can't obtain value can just be the result of optimizations. Try in debug mode to see where it breaks and crashes.